# Three classes dependence - returning data

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, uitableview, urlconnection

I've been thinking for over a day regarding one dependence I came across. I am new in Objective-C, so please take it easy on me.  I didn't know even how to google the problem I came across.

I have three classes:

1. `RootViewController`
2. `HttpRequestWrapper`
3. `ManagementClass`

Where `RootViewController` inherits `ManagementClass`.
(`@interface RootViewController : ManagementClass <UINavigationControllerDelegate>`).

So in `ManagementClass` I call this function:

```
[[self.navigationController topViewController] getTableData];
```

where the `topViewController` is the `RootViewController` (but later I want to change it for any `topViewController` at the moment).

This function `getTableData` calls `HttpRequestWrapper` and in it `URLConnection` is called with all its delegates. But when it comes to the delegate method - `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` I want with `NSNotification` to notify the `RootViewController` that   loading the data from the request is done and to populate the table with the data. But the `NSNotification` does not notify the `RootViewController` even though it is a `topViewController` on the navigation stack.

So my question is how can I get the data back from the `URLConnection` to the `RootViewController`, even though the request was initialized via the `ManagementClass` in a way.

Here is bit of code of my problem:

The class `RootViewController`:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
......

//  Get the data using the class HttpRequstWrapper (where I wrap the request in NSURLConnection)
- (void) getTableData{
    httpRequestWrapper = [HttpRequestWrapper alloc];
    [httpRequestWrapper getXMLDataWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"equipment/xml"]];
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Get Table Data
    [self getTableData];
}

- (void) populateTableData{

    // Maybe change this line that error is shown if no data is found 
           if (httpRequestWrapper.dataFromTheHttpRequest == nil){
        NSLog(@"Data got from the HttpRequestWrapper is nil or empty");
    }

    // Parse the returned data 
    xmlcont = [[XMLController alloc] loadXMLByURL:httpRequestWrapper.dataFromTheHttpRequest];

    // Get the names of the Equipments as names of each Section
    arrayEquipments = [NSMutableArray alloc];
    arrayEquipments = xmlcont.equipments;
    sectionsTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (Equipment *eq in arrayEquipments){
        [sectionsTitles addObject: eq.equipmentName];
    }

    // Reload the data in TableView
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad{
    ....
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(populateTableData) name:@"connectionFinishedLoading" object:nil];

}
```

The class `ManagementClass`:
in the .h file

```
@interface ManagementClass : UITableViewController {}
```

in the .m file

```
@implementation ManagementClass

- (void) refreshPage {
    if ([[self.navigationController topViewController] isKindOfClass: [RootViewController class]]){ 
        [[self.navigationController topViewController] getTableData];
    } 
}
```

And in the `HttpRequestWrapper` class I have:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
......
      if ([urlExtension rangeOfString: @"notification"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFinishedLoading1" object:nil];
        } else if ([urlExtension rangeOfString: @"execution/workflow"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFinishedLoadingPhaseView" object:nil]; execution/workflow

        } else if ([urlExtension rangeOfString: @"equipment/xml"].location != NSNotFound) {
        //[[self.navigationController topViewController] populateTableData];  - not working
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"connectionFinishedLoading" object:nil];
    }
.......
}
```

I want a way to make Controllers as reusable as possible.
I had an idea of putting  `[[self.navigationController topViewController] populateTableData]` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` but the navigation Controller can't be called from the `HttpRequstWrapper`, it simply does not execute. I still can't figure out why. I can only execute the `navigationController` methods with the `ViewController` of the `View` that is visible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you're listening for "connectionFinishedLoading" in RootViewController and you're posting "connectionFinishedLoading1" in HttpRequestWrapper. They have to be the same to be caught by RootViewController

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy paste properly the last part of the if commands. My bad. I edited now with all Ifs now. The whole goal of the code is that  I load the table once the view is presented and next time I want to refresh the table data if there are changes on the server. So the second time I call the getTableData from the Management class, but I need to notify the RootViewController when data has finished loading and reload the data.

Comment: I managed to call  [[self.navigationController topViewController] populateTableData];  in the httpRequestWrapper class by using this method:   MyAppDelegate* appDel = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; and then
            [[appDel.navigationController topViewController] populateTableData];   I think it is not the best solution but it works just fine.